# How to create Vlookup formula to replace old data with new one

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

My company receives weekly updates from different providers.They all give the same type of data but in a different order ( ex: one company will give column A= Name / column B= Quantity / column C= Cargo. When an other will give column A= Cargo / Column B= Name / Column C = Quantity ) . I think I need to create a Vlookup formula that would automatically find the new data, and replace the old one with it in the right place(if the data changed from last week). I understand that the formula will have to be different with every provider since they all have a different format. 
To help you help me, I ll write the order of columns in our Template, followed by the order of one of the providers:
Our template

```
A:Reference Number
B:IMO
C:Vessel Name
D:Commodity
E:Product detail
F:Quantity
G:Departure country
H:Departure port
I:ETA
J:ETB
K:ETD
L:Current status
M:Destination Continent
N:Destination Country
O:Destination Port
P:Charterer
Q:receiver
```

Providers Template:

```
B:Vessel name
C:ETA
D:ETB
E:ETD
F:Departure Country
G:Departure port
H:Destination Continent
I:Destination Country
J:Destination Port
K:Commodity
L:Product detail
M:Quantity
N:Name of vessel
O:IMO
P:Reference code
Q:Charterer
R:Current status.
```

Any idea how to do this???

Comment: How is that related to the **programming language** C?

Comment: This is no coding service. If you have any _specific_ problem, please post a [mcve].

Comment: Provide an example of your data with a screenshot of your worksheets. Remember the key to data manipulation is having uniform source data. If there is no uniformity at all in your data doing this will be hard (if not impossible). However if I am reading you correctly, the lable names are always consistent, just placed in different columns (but with the same spelling, and in the same row). This becomes relatively straightforward but we need to see what your data looks like, how you want the output to look, and an explanation of what you have already tried.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon 
Truth is not all providers templates have the same label names. Some will say product, some will say commodity, others won't even have this label. However, each provider does always use the same labels in the same order ( reason why i understand that I will need a different code for each one of them)
I believe the key will reside in the name of the ship, which is our only constant. The idea would be to Vlookup the name of the ship on the Weekly update, and transfer the new value to the current template. the data most likely to change are the ETA ETB ETD :s

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon 
And btw thank you so much for trying to help me. I recently began using excel and am fairly lost in all this.

Comment: **Tell us what your data looks like, how you want the output to look, and an explanation of what you have already tried.** For example, what is your current process flow? Do you maintain a single excel workbook, and every new order gets copied to a new tab? Or does each supplier have their own tab, and you manually paste the data each time? Or...?

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon 
I created a single workbook on which I just stored our latest data manually. Every week we receive a separate excel file with updated data ( ex: This week ship A was expected, next week ship A will be Loading) Since there isn't really a process flow yet, what do you believe would be the best way? Should I copy past the data to a new sheet, and work from there on? or is there a way to do it from a separate workbook? I am sorry i can't be more precise, i wish i could screen shot to show you but there is confidential info that i can't send :(

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon 
I am researching how to do this as we speak, i ll get back to you once I have a better Idea of what exactly i am doing haha. Thanks again for trying to help. I know it can't be easy to do this without the actual data in front of you .

Comment: Take a look at my answer below and see if that helps you get started.

Answer (score 0):

Okay based on your last response, I'm going to provide a potential solution with some caveats and assumptions.

**Caveats**

A VBA solution may be best here if the data is coming in from multiple source workbooks. However if this happens infrequently it wouldn't save you much time to do a VBA solution. Also if you are unfamiliar with VBA I don't recommend you simply paste in someone else's code that you got online - because it could be malicious, or it could lead you to be unable to actually do your job if some problem with the code arises that you can't fix.

**Assumptions**

-I'm going to assume that each vendor is included in the same workbook, on its own tab. 
-I'm also assuming that the data is going to be somewhat consistent, as you noted in the comments to your question above.
-For now, I'm assuming that you only need a few fields from each vendor, and that those fields are always the same between vendors. This is not necessarily required to use this method, but it simplifies things a bit and will get you start. For now, let's assume you only care about the Vendor name, the cargo type, the quantity, and the expected shipping date.

**Proposed Workflow**

My general advice for someone doing a 'mini-database' in Excel like this is to keep separate tabs for their data dumps, their working formula sheets, and their summary tabs used for display/printing purposes. Keep your coding solutions only to the level that you yourself understand, and don't throw away the raw sourcebooks. Ideally if someone is reviewing / auditing your work they should be able to simply copy & paste in a random data sample and immediately see if it is picking up the right amounts.

So, My proposal would be to have a single summary tab, a data-dump tab for each vendor (also called a "landing page"), and an intermediary formula tab for each vendor.

The **data dump tabs** should contain the data exactly as it comes in from the vendor, without adjustments. Formatting your data-dump tab to match your raw data (rather than formatting your raw data to match your data dump tab) will mean that each time you update it, minimal intervention will be required. This is thus 1 step short of full 'automation'.

The **intermediary formula tabs** for each supplier should be in the same format as each other intermediary formula tab. This will allow for easier pickup on the main summary tab. The purpose of the intermediary formula tabs will be to give you an opportunity to look at that vendor's excel datadump, and determine the best way to pull the fields that you care about for review.

The **summary tab** will simply be a list of all vendor tabs, showing a grid of the fields that you care about from each.

**Steps to complete**

Using the "providers template" that you have in your question, dump that tab into "Provider A data-dump" tab.

In the "Provider A Formulas" tab, we will first type the provider's name as the sheet name. In cell A1, type "Index". In cell B1, type "Reference #". In cell C1, type "Cargo Type". In cell D1, type "Quantity". In cell E1 type "Shipping Date".

Column A will hold an index equal to the number of orders being shipped from that vendor. The formula in A2 will be "=1", and the formula in A3, and copied down, will be:

```
=if(row()<=count('Provider A Data'!M:M),row()-1,"")
```

This will count which row you're on, and if the row you're on is less than the total rows with numbers in the quantity field of the raw data tab, it will show that row number (-1 for the header). Otherwise, it will show a blank.

For the rest of it, if your data is truly consistent, then you can simply set the first cell in row 2 to be equal to a specific cell in the other tab. ie: B2, which shows the reference ID, could be simply:

```
='Provider A Data'!P2
```

Then just drag that down and it will pick it up as you drag. You will use your index key in column A to make sure you have dragged far enough.

There are formula solutions (like vlookup) which could be used to find a specific reference ID in the raw data tab and pull the exact row from another column, but you don't need to use those if you are simply keeping things in the same row-order as they appear in the data dump tab.

Then for your summary tab, simply create some columns that pull in amounts from each vendor. Once you have set up the workbook for the first time, all you'll need to do to update will be drag down rows in the formula tab. If you have further specific questions about how to achieve any of this, please ask in a specific question, noting what you have tried to do, and what part of that has failed.

I hope this helps you get started.

Comment: So I created a separate work book just for the sake of practice, where I only take care of one data provider, let's call him Alphaship. I have 3 Sheets, one is named Alphashipdatadump, second Alphaship, third Alphashipresume. The formula tab (named Alphaship) Has A1:Index A2:"=A1" and A3:=IF(ROW()<=COUNT([Alphashipdatadump]Alphashipdatadump!M:M),ROW()-1,"")
(The program asks me to select a workbook and a Sheet, but I am not sure what to pick.) I thought I should pick the datadump sheet but it just gives me blanks. I used B1:Vessel C1:Status. Which I linked below to the old data

Comment: @CzukDee I'm not sure what your new question is - please edit your original question with more details about what you've tried and what the problem with that has been.

Comment: The formula I place in A3 (and copie down). What should I put as Provider A Data? Alphaship or Alphashipdatadump? And once the program asks me which sheet to update,what should I pick? The datadump sheet or the Alphaship (Formula sheet). Last question is do I need to have a 4th sheet with all the raw data or should this simply be the datadump sheet ?I believe you are absolutely correct in the process, and this method will be much better than Vlookup. Thank you for launching me in the right direction.

Comment: You only need 2 sheets per vendor: the raw data dump, and the formula sheet. Then you need 1 summary sheet for all vendors combined. You should copy the data dump from the original vendor workbook, and paste it into your datadump sheet. The reason it is asking you to select a workbook is because you are referring to a seperate file - which you shouldn't need to do. Does this make sense?